# Split 64-bit value to four 16-bit

Tags: java, 64-bit, bit-manipulation, 16-bit

I have 64 bit values like this:

> 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111
>   1101 0011

Decimal value of given stream of number is -45.

I want to split in four 16-bit values:

1111 1111 1111 1111
1111 1111 1111 1111
1111 1111 1111 1111
1111 1111 1101 0011

The input value is signed long.

How to do that in Java?

So far I've tried on this way:

```
long[] buf = new long[4];
buf[0] =  (l&0xFF);
buf[1] =  (l&0xFF >> 16) & 0XFF;
buf[2] =  (l&0xFF >> 32) & 0XFF;
buf[3] =  (l&0xFF >> 48) & 0XFF;
```

But I think that I mess something with bit shifting logic.

**EDIT**

The correct solution thanks to @Eugene is:

```
long l = 45;

long[] buf = new long[4];
buf[0] =  (l & 0xFFFF);
buf[1] =  l  >> 16 & 0XFFFF;
buf[2] =  l  >> 32 & 0XFFFF;
buf[3] =  l  >> 48 & 0XFFFF;

long result = ( buf[3] & 0xFFFF) << 48 | ( buf[2] & 0xFFFF) << 32 | (buf[1] & 0xFFFF) << 16 | (buf[0] & 0xFFFF);

System.out.println("Decimal: " + result);
System.out.println("Binary: "Long.toBinaryString(result));
```

Comment: Is it stored as a String?  Are your 64bit values called the "input value"?

Comment: It is not stores as string. It is stored like long data type. The part that I don't understand well is bit manipulation. The result should be places in array of four elements, for each group of 16-bits.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). From that second link: "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it." - even if it is no homework...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

you are almost correct (I did way too much typing thinking that you needs the basics also, my bad).

All you have to change is: `buf[1] =  l  >> 16 & 0xFFFF;`

I could have written it differently, but that is probably the easiest to understand:

```
 long t = Long.parseUnsignedLong("1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111010011", 2);

    long twoPower16 = Long.parseLong("1111111111111111", 2);

    long one = t & twoPower16;
    long two = t >> 16 & twoPower16;
    long thr = t >> 32 & twoPower16;
    long fou = t >> 48 & twoPower16;

    System.out.println(Long.toBinaryString(one));
    System.out.println(Long.toBinaryString(two));
    System.out.println(Long.toBinaryString(thr));
    System.out.println(Long.toBinaryString(fou));
```

When you do an `&` operation(it's called a mask), for example :

```
   0101
   0011
   ----
   0001 --> you are keeping the last two bits here
```

and the `>>` is a shift operator. You tell how many bits to shift:

```
 System.out.println(7 >> 1); // 3
```

That's actually `0111 >> 1` --> `0011`, you have shifted `7` on bit to the left.

Comment: @Josef see the edit in my answer - you were *almost* there.

Comment: So, the correct solution would be: buf[0] =  ( l & 0xFF); buf[1] =  l  >> 16 & 0XFF; buf[2] =  l  >> 32 & 0XFF; buf[3] =  l  >> 48 & 0XFF; Right?

Comment: But why when I want to convert back to original on this way long result = ( buf[3] & 0xFF) << 48 | ( buf[2] & 0xFF) << 32 | (buf[1] & 0xFF) << 16 | (buf[0] & 0xFF); I get wrong result?

Comment: @Josef the problem is in `0xFF`, it should be `0xFFFF`

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe I'm doing something wrong but even I change to 0xFFFF i don't get back correct value.
long[] buf = new long[4]; buf[0] =  (l & 0xFFFF); buf[1] =  l  >> 16 & 0XFFFF; buf[2] =  l  >> 32 & 0XFFFF;buf[3] =  l  >> 48 & 0XFFFF;  long result = ( buf[0] & 0xFFFF) << 48 | ( buf[1] & 0xFFFF) << 32 | (buf[2] & 0xFFFF) << 16 | (buf[3] & 0xFFFF);

Comment: Works now, thnks a lot!